# C++ reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

I don't know why this simple code is not working:

```
int main()
{
    const char* c = "ret";
    typedef unsigned char GOK_UINT8;
    typedef GOK_UINT8* pGOK_UINT8;
    const pGOK_UINT8  y = reinterpret_cast<const GOK_UINT8*>(c);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me why the `reinterpret_cast` does not work?

Comment: Also note that `reinterpret_cast` is a very blunt tool that should be used very sparingly.

Comment: Hint: Taking compound statements apart into their atoms and placing them on seperate lines is a good first step to assert the problem really *is* in the piece of code you think it is. (See my comment to sbi.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can someone tell me why the reinterpret_cast should not work?

AFAICS, the `reinterpret_cast` should work fine, but the assignment afterwards should cause an error.

That's because a `const GOK_UINT8*` is a non-`const` pointer to `const` `GOK_UINT8` objects, while a `const pGOK_UINT8` is a `const` pointer to non-`const` objects.
The former protects the object referred to, the latter the pointer referring to the object. If the assignment would be allowed, you could then change the object that the `const GOK_UINT8*` meant to protect from changing.

---

Note that `typedef`ed pointers behave strange that way. That's because of the strange declaration syntax of `const` in (C and thus also in) C++: *A `const` protects the thing to its left, unless there isn't anything, then it protects the thing to its right.* So in `T const` and in `T const*`, the object of type `T` is protected, while in `T* const` the pointer to an object of type `T` is protected. If you have

```
typedef T* TPtr;
```

then `TPtr const` again makes the pointer `const`. So does `const TPtr`. A `typedef`ed pointer either points to `const` or non-`const` objects, you can't change that. You can't stuff a `const` into the vicinity of `TPtr` and expect that to protect the objects the pointer refers to.

(BTW, this is why STL classes have to define both an `iterator` and a `const_iterator`.)

Comment: +1, correct answer. @Gokul: Try this instead of line 6: `const GOK_UINT8* tmp = reinterpret_cast<const GOK_UINT8*>(c); const pGOK_UINT8 y = tmp;`. You will see the reinterpret_cast works fine, it's the type mismatch in the assignment that results in an error. That being said, be aware that your code exhibits about as many bad coding practices as it has lines... I hope this is for experimentation only. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yep sbi is correct.

Modified your code accordingly,

```
const char* c = "ret";
typedef unsigned char GOK_UINT8;
typedef const GOK_UINT8* pGOK_UINT8;
pGOK_UINT8 y = reinterpret_cast<const GOK_UINT8*>(c);
printf("%s", y);
```